# react-native audio call app without webrtc

Tags: android, react-native, webrtc, audio-streaming

I want to add group audio chat facilities in a simple react-native game. Is there any third-party app or something that will handle this. I tried webrtc but I am new so it's become hard for me. So I want a simple solution for this. If there is any easier solution for this It will be helpful for me.

I am using :-

1. react-native
2. firebase
3. node js

Answer (score 1):

As for now, I am developing such an aplication, but I can find any alternantives to webrtc.
You can use some libraries, which are still built on to of webrtc, but they ease life a bit
These include

1. https://openbase.com/js/react-native-immediate-phone-call (for your
   case)
2. https://openbase.com/js/react-native-webrtc
3. https://openbase.com/js/simple-peer
4. https://openbase.com/js/peerjs
5. https://openbase.com/js/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc
6. https://openbase.com/js/opentok-react
7. https://openbase.com/js/discord-rpc

and so on

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31059666)